# Does bootstrap-grid uses jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

#### Epilogue:

We are using **Angular 9** and as with every frontend framework, they highly discourage developers to refrain from using other JS library along with their framework to manipulate DOM.

#### My Problem:

So I don't want to add `jquery` in `angular.json` and I need **bootstrap** only for it's **grid**. Since that's the case I don't think adding `ng-bootstrap` or likes would be a good idea.

#### My Question:

Will importing just `bootstrap-grid` in without `jquery` work?

Comment: No grid is 100% based on CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested, Bootstrap Grid (`bootstrap-grid`) works without `jquery`.

Here's my `angular.json` gist

```
{
  "projects": {
     "styles": [
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css",
       "src/styles.scss"
     ],
     "scripts": []
  }
}
```